# Sails.js oneToOne pointing to last on oneToMany

Tags: associations, sails.js, waterline

A design wonder in sails.js and waterline models.

I have a "bear" model and a "location" one. They hold a oneToMany association ("bear can have multiple location over time").

**bear.js**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    location: {
      collection: 'location',
      via: 'bear'
    }
  }
};
```

**location.js**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    timestamp: {
      type: 'datetime',
      required: true
    },
    bear: {
      model: 'bear'
    }
  }
};
```

I'm trying to make a "oneToOne" association grabbing the last location of a bear (`lastLocation`), and wondering what's the best solution :

- Trying to override ToJSON on bear, fetching last location (doesn't seem to work, because ToJSON is hardly synchronous so I can't make it wait for an asynchronous `find`)
- Creating a real oneToOne relationship and adding a hook AfterCreate on location to update that "lastLocation" association ?
- Override blueprint create on location ?
- Override blueprint add on bear ?
- Any other idea ?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your answer here?

> Creating a real oneToOne relationship and adding a hook AfterCreate on location to update that "lastLocation" association ?

You should create an additional attribute on bear called `lastLocation:{model:'location'}`, and automatically update that after each location is created on the associated bear. Their are otherways to do this, but if the last location is something that is read a lot, then this will probably be your best approach.

Now this is a little bit of opinion based as there would be many factors involved in your design to say for sure, but I think you will be fine using this approach.

Comment: Hi. And thanks about this =) Indeed, that is the way I experimented this afternoon because it seemed to be the cleanest to me... It basically works but however, I fighting with something : When I call `GET /location/create?bear=1`, then afterCreate hook is called with a newly created location with it's `bear` property set, but when I do it via the `GET /bear/1/locations/add?myproperties` shortcut, the hook seems to be called **before** the association is made, and `bear` is undefined, leaving me in a state I can't guess which bear it concerns =(

Comment: this is getting a little complicated. You may need to create gist or something to show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Also, why are you making a query to get the bear's last location? I updated your code without that, here http://goo.gl/dfmYZ2. You really need to put code somewhere other than in here. Depending on your setup, will a location be switched from one bear to another? Probably not, so there probably is not a need for it on the afterUpdate callback.

Comment: Dear Meeker, thanks about this piece of code. This was in order to do some later some comparison or stuff (lastLocation is not populated, and if I go with "populate" on the Bear find, that makes a mess).

Comment: About "AfterUpdate" I explained it : It's not a "change location's bear" matter, it's a "set location's bear" matter (manually creating location, leaving bear undefined, then defining it : notice that bear is not required)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with :

- **model/Bear.js** - last location association

  ```
   lastLocation: {
       model: 'location'
   }
  ```
- **model/Location.js** - `afterCreate` hook

  ```
  afterCreate: function(insertedLocation, callback) {
      if(!insertedLocation.bear) {
          return callback();
      }

      Bear.findOneById(insertedLocation.bear, function(err, bear) {
          if(err) {
              return callback(err);
          }

          Location.findOneById(bear.lastLocation, function(err, oldLastLocation) {
              bear.lastLocation = insertedLocation.id;

              bear.save(function(err) {
                  return callback(err);
              });
          });
      });
  }
  ```

  the `if(!insertedLocation.bear)` test is the key
- I repeated similar code inside `afterUpdate` hook

  ```
  afterUpdate: function(updatedLocation, callback) {
      if(!updatedLocation.bear) {
          return callback();
      }

      Bear.findOneById(updatedLocation.bear, function(err, bear) {
          if(err) {
              return callback(err);
          }

          Location.findOneById(bear.lastLocation, function(err, oldLastLocation) {
              bear.lastLocation = updatedLocation.id;

              bear.save(function(err) {
                  return callback(err);
              });
          });
      });
  }
  ```

adding a test in order to prevent updating bear each time we update lastLocation

- One could add some `PublishUpdate()` logic